# Design Automation doesn't end work properly with 2019 revit

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk, revit, autodesk-designautomation

I have some unexpected behavior.
When I work with the 2020 engine and 2018 everything correct.
But when I use the same instruction for the 2019 engine, the job doesn't close even after call OnShutdown method.
I don't have an uploading phase for this job, so after OnShutdown call, it should end.
But for some reason job closes only after manual canceling.
[design automation report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEZe8.png)

In this sample, I wait 2 minutes before cancel. But also was 10 and 20 minutes of waiting.

Comment: Hi, @j.doe, does this hanging happen on some revit file on 2019 only?  2020 and 2018 work correctly with the **same** revit file and appbundles?

Comment: What exact code are you running? Have you tried executing the same in all three versions of the Revit desktop .NET API?

Comment: @JeremyTammik I created assembly instances and change parameters for them. 
In the desktop version, I tried only in Revit 2020 but for 2019 I use the same instruction. 
And in the screenshot, as you can see dll ended successfully because the method OnShutdown was called, but the job ended only when I canceled it or by timeout.

Comment: @EmmaZhu Yep, I tried to run with the same file and the same dll in Revit 2020 and Revit 2019. With 2020 everything works fine. The Revit file has a 2019 version so design automation Revit upgraded it to 2020 and run dll successfully.

For DA 2018 I use the same dll but another file. and it works too.

Comment: Thank you guys a lot.
Looks like it will be just some temporary problem.

I tried right now the same activity, same file, and the same bundle and it works fine.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

By the way, in the report from DA 2018 2019, I see [one log-line](https://i.imgur.com/pCJjaMt.png) which I didn't see in 2020.
Could you please tell me what does it mean?

Comment: @j.doe, this line is from QT, you can ignore it which is from revit side. :) Thanks for reporting the issue and glad it works now. BTW, we do have a known issue about hanging of some 2019 job for which we will deploy a fix. I was asking to see if you had the same case. Let us know if you need any help further!